# Are values passed by reference or by value in Microsoft Excel VBA script?

Tags: php, excel, vba, xlsx

I'm trying to convert VBA to PHP for a project. I saw a function like:

```
Private Function OptimiseAnnealing(ByRef A As Double)
```

If ByRef is enabled by default in VBA, why is there a need for such a keyword?

Also, if the variables are passed by reference by default does that mean that when we call a subroutine (Sub) in VBA, any changes made to the variables in the Subroutine also reflects back to the variables in the function that invokes it?

Comment: There is no need to use `ByRef` if it's implied by default. That doesn't mean it's not good practice. And yes, changes to a passed variable as `ByRef` will reflect back.

Comment: _"...why is there a need for such a keyword?"_ My answer to this would be that many of us appreciate explicit coding. I've seen some that will place this when they explicitly expect there to be returned changes to the variable that is calling the routine.